# RSpec controller response body is returning string name of response class instead of response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, response, controllers

I am testing a controller in rails using rspec.  The response body is just the string of the response instance and not the actual response.  My test is below.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe CampusesController do
    render_views

    before(:each) do
        sign_in :auth_role, 'test@test.com', 'password'
    end

    it 'should retrieve all campuses as json' do
        FactoryGirl.create(:basic_campus)
        get 'index', :format => :json
        ap response.body
    end

end
```

response.body is the string "#<ActionDispatch::Response:0x007f87d6ee8800>".  How do I get the actual json response?  When I go through the browser, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with declarative authorization and devise.  This answer helped me figure out how to set up my tests. [Stringify Keys Error with Devise and Declarative Testing with RSpec in Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827247/stringify-keys-error-with-devise-and-declarative-testing-with-rspec-in-rails-3-1)